# How to get postcss config working with Nuxt?

Tags: postcss, nuxt.js, postcss-import

My Nuxt project doesn't pick up the config for postcss-import from nuxt.config.ts:

```
build: {
    postcss: {
        plugins: {
            "postcss-import": {
                path: ["../assets/css", "../components/@css", "../components"]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get an error like `Error: Can't resolve 'style.css' in /projectroot/pages`.

The same config in `postcss.config.js` is picked up properly. To test, if I change postcss.config.js to point to non-existing directories, the error becomes: `Error: Failed to find 'style.css' in [list of configured directories]`.

What should I do to get this working from nuxt.config.ts? Note that I'm using Typescript (nuxt-ts).

Comment: I am not using postcss but in my nuxt config I use the `~` when refering to the folders. e.g: `"~/plugins/stackify"` . try to replace the '`..`' with '`~`'

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yeah, I tried that but that doesn't solve it. With postcss.config.js the error message indicates the list of directories it tries, but with nuxt.config.ts it doesn't. It just doesn't seem to pick up the config.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I use it:

I import a css file as usual and add postcss config on the *build* property of `nuxt.config.js`

```
  css: ['~/assets/css/tailwind.css'],
  build: {
    postcss: {
      plugins: {
        'postcss-import': true,
      }
    }
  }
```

[From NuxtJS docs](https://nuxtjs.org/faq/postcss-plugins/)

With this config I can also use the `<style lang="postcss">` tag inside Vue files.

Answer (score 0):

I had a file called postcssrc.js

```js
    "plugins": {
          "postcss-import": {},
          "postcss-url": {},
          // to edit target browsers: use "browserslist" field in package.json
          "autoprefixer": {}
          }
```

I deleted it and in the file nuxt.config.js add the next code:

```js
        build: {
        postcss: {
          plugins: {
          "postcss-import": {},
          "postcss-url": {},
          // to edit target browsers: use "browserslist" field in package.json
          "autoprefixer": {}
          }
        }
      }
```

Then in the package.json I ran the scripts:

```js
"build":"nuxt build"
```